# What considerations should be kept in mind to ensure accurate matching of elastic constants in VASP calculations?

Tags: vasp, physical-properties-of-materials, 2d-lattice, elasticity, vaspkit

What factors should be considered to ensure accurate alignment of elastic constants obtained from VASP calculations with those reported in the literature for 2D hexagonal graphene?

Comment: +1 but please make a body for your question. For example, you can write a little bit about why you are doing these calculations, what your background is (e.g. what you know so far), or what type of materials you are considering.